# How do I direct my audio to a bluetooth device?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have successfully paired my "headset" (actually its a speaker) with KDE. Now where can I go to tell it to send audio to the speaker. My multimedia settings don't seem to list the device as an option. I did a complete reboot and reconnected the device via the bluetooth panel but still I don't have any extra options.

[image]

[image]

The 'Backend' tab says I am using Phonon GStreamer